# are subdirectories in the 'server' folder only accessible on the server?

Tags: meteor, structure

Meteor documentation states

```
Meteor ensures that any file in any directory named server/ will only be available on the server
```

but what about subdirectories (and their corresponding files) in the server folder? Are they only accessible via the server too? e.g...

```
server/
   server.js
   myfolder/
      fileIOnlyWantToBeAccessibleByTheServer.js
      anotherFileIOnlyWantToBeAccessibleByTheServer.js
client/
   client.js
common/
   common.js
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out? Just try to import in `client.js` some content, that is exported in `server/myfolder/fileIOnlyWantToBeAccessibleByTheServer.js` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sub-directories of server are not sent to the client. from here: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories

> Any directory named server/ is not loaded on the client.

thought it doesn't explicitly spell out sub-directories, i think it's implied from that statement. also, from experience, i can say the subdirs are not sent.